# How to choose collation of SQL Server database

Tags: sql, sql-server, collation

What if I want to use database to store different groups of special characters, how do I choose which collation to use? For example, if I set collation to Croatian and want to use Russian cyrillic, japanese characters except croatian special characters - which collation should I use?

Thanks,
Ilija

Answer (score 12, accepted):

- You'd use nvarchar to store the data
- COLLATION defines sorting and comparing

That means you can store Croatian, Russian and Japanese in the same column.

But when you want to compare (`WHERE MyColumn = @foo`) or sort (`ORDER BY MyColumn`) you'll not get what you expect because of the collation.

However, you can use the COLLATE clause to change it if needed.
eg `ORDER BY MyColumn COLLATE Japanese_something`

I'd go for your most common option that covers most of your data. [MSDN has this maybe useful article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144260.aspx)

Comment: What would the most common option tend to be, if you want to include as many types of characters as possible? (eg all unicode).

Comment: @andrew I believe they mean use nvarchar for storage and probably default collate to the most common query scenario. I'm guessing collation is mainly interesting for indexing/sorting