# What collation to use for SQL Server database?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

which collation do I need to choose? SQL Server 2008

I've found a nice and related post on stackoverflow.com regarding this question:
[How to choose collation of SQL Server database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4552882/how-to-choose-collation-of-sql-server-database)

So If I understand well (ref above link):

- collation is used for sorting and comparing):
- NVARCHAR is use for store data.

**collation properties/parms**

- CI specifies case-insensitive
- CS specifies case-sensitive
- AI specifies accent-insensitive
- AS specifies accent-sensitive

I need to create a database and will store Turkish and English, I'll choose CI and AI. I don't want case sensitive and no accent sensitive, so it's easy. I think this is clear for English, but Turkish has some special characters like üçö etc.

**Question:**

Since collation is not related to STORING data and I'll use `NVARCHAR`, **why** should I choose collation `Turkish_100_CI_AI`, I can also use `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`, which is also my default on my SQL Server. Both are Latin script.

It's the same question for storing ENGLISH and FRENCH in the same database... Why should I use `French_100_CI_AI` in stead of `Latin1_General_100_CI_AI`?

Can someone advice ? Am I wrong?

Comment: You're wrong that the Latin1 character set includes all the characters for those languages. It doesn't. Nor does the Latin1 collation make the same decisions about character equality and ordering as the language-specific collations.

Comment: @Dan: could you please clarify. ok I just a site the latin characterset. Some Turkish characters are not there... But it does for French...So if there is all french Char in there, I can use for French-English... not?  "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537495(v=vs.85).aspx"... -2- why does Latin 1 collation not make the decision?

Comment: In case it's not obvious (it's not highlighted in your question, nor the one linked to), sorting and comparing affects the definition of `UNIQUE` constraints - so if you decide to collate `CI_AI`, you can't store two values in a unique column that only differ by case (or accents)

Comment: Sorry ,it's not clear. do you mean : In column "Name" or "Address" -  Can I store here French/English when it's Latin1_100_CI_AI? French chars are in Latin1. Can I take this statement. If the chars are in Latin1 set (for any language).. I can use Latin1. -> is this correct?

Answer (score 8):

You can set the collation explicitly for each column using the COLLATE clause, if your data model allows you to separate data into language-specific columns.

You can also apply the COLLATE clause to a SELECT statement (e.g. you keep all language data in the same place, and only filter by language in a SELECT).

As far as I'm aware Turkish (sort order) is not covered by Latin1.

Comment: you're right. I just checked the char set latin 1 "http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms537495(v=vs.85).aspx" but what about French/English... I see Latin 1 contains the French characters... so I can use Latin1?

Answer (score 7):

**Collation** refers to a set of rules that determine how data is sorted and compared. Character data is sorted using rules that define the correct character sequence, with options for specifying case-sensitivity, accent marks, kana character types and character width.

**Case sensitivity**

If **A** and **a**, **B** and **b**, etc. are treated in the same way then it is case-insensitive. A computer treats **A** and **a** differently because it uses **ASCII code** to differentiate the input.

**Accent sensitivity**

If **a** and **á**, **o** and **ó** are treated in the same way, then it is accent-insensitive. A computer treats **a** and **á** differently because it uses ASCII code for differentiating the input. Like The ASCII value of **a** is **97** and **á** is **225**.

**Kana Sensitivity**

When Japanese kana characters Hiragana and Katakana are treated differently, it is called Kana sensitive.

**Width sensitivity**

When a single-byte character (half-width) and the same character when represented as a double-byte character (full-width) are treated differently then it is width sensitive.

More info can be found [here](https://www.databasejournal.com/features/mssql/article.php/3302341/SQL-Server-and-Collation.htm). I hope this answer helped.